# Importance of ping - pong in udp p2p communication

Tags: udp, sockets, p2p

I am quite new to socket programming. I was trying to make p2p communication using udp and did finally made it. While writing a program, the point I have observed is that communication between two peers does not take place if packets are not send from both sides. I read somewhere that in networking its called ping-pong.

I want to know why it is designed like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you encountered is likely due to firewalls and NAT routers.

The solution is to use [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) techniques (Most useful information is the various techniques listed under See Also).